# Getting Yii to play nicely with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, yii

I've setup a database connection in my config file, and if I print out the contents of Yii::app() I can find the database connection details, and they are correct.

When trying to use the Gii model generator tool, however, it falls down on me.

```
53    public function init() {
54 echo '<pre>';
55 print_r(Yii::app()->db);
56 echo '</pre>';
57 die();
58 Yii::app()->db = array(
59             'connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server=sti-hq2k8; Database=TrulinXLive',
60             'username' => 'jzumbrum',
61             'password' => 'my_super_secret_password',
62         'charset' => 'utf8',
63         'tablePrefix' => 'tbl',
64         );
65         if(Yii::app()->db===null)
66             throw new CHttpException(500,'An active "db" connection is required to run this generator.');
```

Exception Message:

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The given attribute is only supported on the PDOStatement object.
```

Config settings:

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server=servername; Database=database',
        'username' => 'jzumbrum',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'GB2312',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl',
    )
```

Comment: remove the `tablePrefix`, and try?

Comment: thanks for the assistance, so nice to have people give me suggestions to solve my difficulties.  Really loving yii so far; it's by far my favorite PHP framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I remember, I think I stopped having problems once I disabled emulating prepared statements:

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server=servername; Database=database',
    'username' => 'jzumbrum',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'GB2312',
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl',
    'emulatePrepare' =>false
)
```

Other possible problems/ fixes available here: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/17998-use-sqlsrv-with-php-53x-and-yii/

Comment: thanks for your help, especially the link.  After reading through those suggestions I eventually thought to try localhost for the hell of it.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped and you figured it out. Still vividly remember the pain of getting Yii working with SQL Server myself :-)

Comment: But why? I need emulate prepare to be able to get around the default 2100 parameter limit in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue was I could connect to the sql server on localhost.  Although I'm not intimately familiar with how this server is setup, I was pretty sure that I was on a different machine, so they must have some crazy tunneling or something setup.

I find it odd that when I gave the wrong password it told me there was a connection error, but when I specified the wrong server address it gave me this other error instead.  Perhaps it was resolving, just had something else blocking it that way.

Config changed to:

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server=localhost; Database=database',
    'username' => 'jzumbrum',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'GB2312',
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl',
)
```

Comment: Another issue I had was that I'm using multiple files for the dev, production, and default configurations.  When I left a default DB connection in the main.php file, it didn't get overwritten by the production file.